Ghost images when copying but not when scanning or printing
Samsung M2876ND MFC is causing ghost images when any document is copied via the copy button on the device. The ghost images do not overlap the real images, but are printed several inches away.
But when scanning anything to PC or printing anything from PC, there is no issue of ghosting. The ghosting issue appears and disappears seemingly randomly. If fuser issue, shouldn't the issue exist when printing as well? What is the technical explanation behind this?

In the past when I had printing quality issues it ended up being printer driver issues. We need to know more information about your setup

Can you test making a copy with the PC off? If the issue persists, you know it's in the multi-function printer, having nothing to do with PC or its drivers. If so, then contact Samsung for help.

@DrMoishePippik Even when nothing is connected, it still causes ghosting. But demo page (which can be printed directly from the printer) doesn't have the issue.

@Ramhound I don't see how it can be driver issue. I did not even connect the device to the computer when the ghosting issue started.
